# move_base is not working properly

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
[ WARN] [1588520680.083051590, 74.492000000]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 10.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.3410 seconds

[ WARN] [1588520680.082264978, 74.492000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 10.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.3410 seconds
```

why do I get this error when I'm launching move_base
when I'm launching the same move_base for turtlebot then there's no error

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351277/move_base-is-not-working-properly/) by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by reducing the frequency from 10 to 3 now it's working perfectly fine.

---

Originally posted by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) with karma: 31 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfvm0001](https://answers.ros.org/users/59247/lfvm0001/) on 2020-09-16**:
Hi, which frequency and in which file do you reduce it? thanks